# Date loop overflow

Tags: excel, vba, date, while-loop, runtime-error

I have two dates, both in a named cell.
Range("NewStartDate").Value = 24/07/2022 and Range("FinishDate").Value = 31/12/2023

I need all columns to have heading which is a date 7 days after previous column, i.e.
A1 is NewStartDate, B1 is NewStartDate+7, C1 is NewStartDate + 7*2, etc. and it will end once we reach the FinishDate.

I created this loop

```
Sub FillInDates()


Dim i as Integer, d as Date, x as Date


Range("NewStartDate").Value = "24/07/2022"
Range("FinishDate").Value = "31/12/2023"

d = Range("NewStartDate").Value
i = 1

Do While x < FinishDate
     Range("NewStartDate").Offset(0, i).Value = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), Day(d) + (7*i)
     x = Range("NewStartDate").Offset(0, i).Value
     i = i + 1
Loop 

End Sub
```

It fills in the following column with the correct next week, however it never stops and I get an overflow error. Why is it not able to stop once we get past end date??

Comment: How is `FinishDate` defined? Also you have a lot of interaction with the Range objects which is quite inefficient. It would be much faster to populate a 1xN 2D array and then copy that array to the whole header range.

Comment: What do you mean how is it defined? It's the value has the same format as the value of x, and is 31/12/2023.

Comment: The FinishDate and x variables have no initial value in your code

Comment: Sorry, they do in my macro I have just only included loop as my overal code is much much larger. See Edit

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else - if I run the code you posted (and adding `FinishDate = Range("FinishDate")`) it does what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error but I can recommend using arrays instead of interacting with the spreadsheet one cell at a time - it is much faster.

Your code could look like this:

```
Sub FillInDates()

  Dim StartDate As Date
  Dim FinishDate As Date
  
  StartDate = Range("NewStartDate")
  FinishDate = Range("FinishDate")
  
  Dim i As Long
  Dim DateArray As Variant
  
  ReDim DateArray(1 To 1, 1 To Int((FinishDate - StartDate) / 7)) As Variant
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(DateArray, 2)
    DateArray(1, i) = StartDate + i * 7
  Next i
  
  Range("NewStartDate").Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(DateArray, 2)) = DateArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Sequence Using a Dictionary

- Since things are not all clear (to me), I've produced this little investigation.
- The named ranges (cells) are named ranges of workbook scope in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).
- The worksheet to be written to is the active sheet which can be a worksheet in another workbook.
- It looks preferable to use a *For...Next* loop with *Step* to loop over the range of the dates.
- Since the results are unique, I've pretended that I don't know how to calculate the number of the resulting dates and chose to write them to the *keys* of a dictionary which conveniently are already 'stored' in a 1D array (one row) for easy copying to the worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FillInDates()

    ' Reference the source workbook ('swb'), the workbook containing
    ' the named ranges (cells).
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Attempt to reference the active sheet ('dsh').
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Validate the active sheet.
    If dsh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the active sheet is a worksheet, the destination worksheet.
    If dsh.Type <> xlWorksheet Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet selected.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If the active workbook is not the workbook containing this code,
    ' reference it ('dwb') and activate the workbook containing this code
    ' ('swb') to be able to use the workbook-scope named ranges (cells).
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    
    If Not swb Is ActiveWorkbook Then
        Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
        swb.Activate
    End If
    
    ' Just an example, this doesn't belong in the code.
    Range("NewStartDate").Value = #12/31/2023#
    Range("FinishDate").Value = #7/24/2022#
    
    ' Validate the contents of the named ranges (cells)
    ' and write them (the dates) to variables ('nDate','fDate')
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    
    cValue = Range("NewStartDate").Value
    If Not IsDate(cValue) Then
        MsgBox "'" & CStr(cValue) & "' is not a date.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim nDate As Date: nDate = cValue

    cValue = Range("FinishDate").Value
    If Not IsDate(cValue) Then
        MsgBox "'" & CStr(cValue) & "' is not a date.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim fDate As Date: fDate = cValue
    
    If nDate > fDate Then
        MsgBox "The new start date (" & CStr(nDate) _
            & ") is greater than the finish date (" & CStr(fDate) & ").", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If it was not the workbook containing this code,
    ' activate the initially active workbook, the destination workbook.
    If Not dwb Is Nothing Then dwb.Activate
    
    ' Write the dates to the 'keys' of a dictionary ('dict').
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim d As Date
    
    For d = nDate To fDate Step 7
        dict(d) = Empty
    Next d
    
    ' Write the dates from the dictionary to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim cc As Long: cc = dict.Count
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    With dsh.Range("A1").Resize(, cc)
        ' Write the values from the 'keys' of the dictionary
        ' to the destination range.
        .Value = dict.keys
        ' Format copied data.
        .Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ' Clear to the right.
        With .Resize(, dsh.Columns.Count - .Column - cc + 1).Offset(, cc)
            .Clear
            .ColumnWidth = 8.43
        End With
    End With

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Dates filled in.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```